# Need help understanding recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

So in my `class` we are studying recursive functions. But I just do not understand how they work.

I'll use this code as an example.

```
// n is written to the screen vertically
// with each digit on a separate line.

void write_vertical(int n) {

    if (n < 10) 
    {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
    else   // n is two or more digits long
    { 
        write_vertical(n/10);
        cout << (n % 10) << endl;
    }
}
```

So if int `n = 123;` it will print each digit on its own line.How does this happen? how does this function work step by step?

Comment: Try writing it out (math functions evaluated) by hand to see what's happening.

Comment: Pencil and Paper ;) , will help on this question . Testing it by giving it random n numbers

Comment: Your debugger has a feature to let you step through the program. Use it!

Comment: I tried to upvote @LightnessRacesinOrbit 's comment too many times and broke something.

Comment: Recursion has already been explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120121/need-help-understanding-recursion).

Comment: @KerrekSB Careful, you might cause brain overflow with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Testing by random number (13)

Let's take 13 for an example. Well it's not less than 10, so it will execute the `else` block, and it will immediately execute the function itself with 13/10, which (as an integer) is 1. Now 1 is less than 10, so it will print 1 onto the screen with a new line because of `endl`. Now it will return back to the previous function call it had (before calling the function again with argument 1) and execute `13%10`. 13 modulus 10 is 3, since its remainder becomes 3, with a new line (again because of `endl`). And voila, you printed the number in a vertical line!

### For future

You should use a pencil and a paper, and debug it yourself manually just like we did above. **OR** even better use a debugger like [**GDB**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)! [**This**](http://www.math.bas.bg/~nkirov/2005/netb151/debugging-with-gdb.html) is an excellent quick startup on how to debug with GDB.

Answer (score 1):

1:

```
if(123 < 10)     // fails
    cout << 123; // skipped
else
{
    recurse(123 / 10); // recurse(12) converted to int
    cout << 123 % 10; // i'll be back here wait
}
```

2:

```
if(12 < 10)     // fails
    cout << 12; // skipped
else
{
    recurse(12 / 10); // recurse(1)
    cout << 12 % 10; // wiat I'll be back
}
```

3:

```
if(1 < 10)      // succeeds! so now else executed
    cout << 1; // printed
```

nothing is below until return of functions so we return 
to 2:

```
cout << 12% 10; // (12 % 10 = 2) was wating it's its time
```

continue below: nothing below so return from function 2 to 1:

in 1:

```
cout << 123 % 10; // it was waiting so now it's its time
cout << 123 % 10; // 123 % 10 = 3
```

go below: nothing untile the end of function so retrun to main
where function was called first time (to the line after the call )

the result: 123

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simple. Assume you've already written your function; then use it.

Here it's the other way around - you are trying to figure out what the function does. Just the same, when you call it, it always does the same stuff.

So, in a general case of a number `n > 10`, what is `n/10` (integer division)? It's that number without its last decimal digit.

What's `n % 10`? It's the number's last decimal digit.

So, your definition reads:

```
doing_something for a number `n` IS

    doing_it for this number without its last decimal digit 
                         (if there's something left, that is);

    then printing its last decimal digit and a newline after it.
```

That's all.